# Binding to a local Service from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

My application has the following components:

2 Activities

A `Service` and a

`BroadcastReceiver`

Whenever the user updates the system time, my broadcast receiver receives the `Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED`. Now when this happens I want to reschedule a `Handler` in my `Service`. How do I bind to a Service within my `BroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service can catch the intent directly without any BroadcastReceiver help.

Can be done by adding intent-filter to your service. There are two ways to do that:

1. by static definition at AndroidManifest.xml file ( [link text](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) ) )
2. you can register receiver in the code context.registerReceiver(your_receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED));

Comment: Ok, after adding the static definition to the Manifest, how do I process the intent within the service (Incase my service is already running)? Is there any methods I should override?

Comment: Probably: onCreate() { Intent intent = getIntent(); }

Comment: "Incase my service is already running" - ok, you can back to proxy BroadcastReceiver and call  startService(), then 'onStartCommand' will be invoked at your service.

Comment: Great job @Damian Kołakowski. Worked for me.