# How to create a notification similar to Play Music app from Google

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a notification that is very similar to what the "Play Music" app from Google uses.

[image: Play Music app notification]

Few questions that hopefully someone can answer.

1. Is this notification done with custom RemoteViews?
2. Is the X for closing the widget part of the NotificationCompat.Builder APIs? or simply part of a custom RemoteView?
3. If it is all custom views how can I set a custom RemoteView for minimized and maximized states?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, all of that is done with custom `RemoteViews`. You'll see in the docs for [`Notification`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html), there's a field for [`bigContentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#bigContentView) along with [`contentView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#contentView).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Took me a little messing around until I found out I had to first build the Notification and then I could set the bigContentView.

Comment: @Kabuko gives me a suggestion. I build a notification big view using RemoteView to control play/pause like this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508369/how-to-create-a-notification-similar-to-play-music-app-from-google) All are right but when i click device back button and out from the application click event(Play/Pause/Forward/Close) button doesn't work.Please help me.

Comment: @HelalKhan Feel free to create a new question with more details. The comments here aren't the right place for that though.

Answer (score 5):

I know I am very late to answer, but this is for new people trying out media notifications.

1. No need to use `RemoteViews`. We can now simply use `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()`. It works perfectly as needed, and brings uniformity in the `Media` consumption experience.
2. When using MediaStyle notifications there will be no X button for versions > Lollipop. Rather we make the notification dismissable when in Paused state. In such cases the process to be followed is shown in the this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828482/adding-a-terminate-playback-button-using-android-l-notification-mediastyle/40122983#40122983).
3. The MediaStyle notification has `setShowActionsInCompactView()` to define which all actions to show in Compact mode. The following is a snippet:

   ```
       notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_play, "Play",
                   createPlayIntent());

       notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.notification_next, "Next", createNextIntent())
               .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
               .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
               .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                       .setShowCancelButton(true)
                       .setCancelButtonIntent(createPlayIntent())
                       .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2);
   ```

This should help you in setting up the whole Media notification as needed. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

1. create statusbar_expanded.xml in res/layout-v16/

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/notification_expanded_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/notification_expanded_height"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/notification"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:divider="?android:listDivider"
    android:dividerPadding="12.0dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/play_controls_notification"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10.0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_playback_rew_jb_dark" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playpause"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/play_controls_notification"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10.0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_playback_pause_jb_dark" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/play_controls_notification"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="10.0dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_playback_ff_jb_dark" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="1.0px"
    android:layout_above="@id/buttons"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:background="?android:dividerHorizontal" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="8.0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_notification_holo_dark" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textarea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/stop"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/notification_padding"
    android:paddingTop="8.0dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trackname"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2. notification.bigContentView assiginment RemoteView

Comment: Need suggestion. All are right but when i click device back button and    out from the application click event(Play/Pause/Forward/Close) button doesn't work.Please help me.

Comment: thumbs up for the         

style="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"

Thanks my friend. luv ya