# how add music player for android in notification bar?

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I write a music player, and there is a need to hang a widget player in notification bar. how it can be implemented ? can be an example?
P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [How to create a notification similar to Play Music app from Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508369/how-to-create-a-notification-similar-to-play-music-app-from-google)

If you read through the [notification](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) docs, you'll see you can make it persistent and set a custom layout.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Understood. In that case, I propose to mark this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508369/how-to-create-a-notification-similar-to-play-music-app-from-google.